# sorting items in RadListBox on destination listbox when trasferring

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

how can I sort the destination list when transferring based on the "Text" so it will look something like

```
A
B
C
```

Now it seems like the transfer button causes a postback, but i am not sure where to add it and how to sort it since it is being binded in a method like this (the destination listbox)

```
protected void BindDestinationCollection()
{
    StoreItems storeItems =new StoreItems();

    DataSet dsStoreItems= storeItems.GetDestinationItemsByID(ItemID);
    DataView view = new DataView();

    if (dsStoreItems.Tables[0] != null && dsStoreItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lstDestinationListBox.Items.Clear();
        view = dsStoreItems.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "ItemName ASC";
        lstDestinationListBox.DataSource = view;

         lstDestinationListBox.DataTextField = "ItemName";
         lstDestinationListBox.DataValueField = "ItemID";
         lstDestinationListBox.DataBind();
     }  
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the markup too, please?

Comment: Can you show me what you're doing in lstSourceList_Transferring? I think that's where the magic needs to happen.

Comment: added the transfer stuff a bit messy - i also tried adding a BindDestinationCollection() from the transferring event but it gives an error when trying to move back to the source list "something related to nullreference", but without it it works fine

Comment: Ahh figured it out...  Gotta sort on Pre_Render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After transferring the items, in the OnTransferred event handler, use the following code:

```
//sorts items by text
RadListBox1.Sort();
```

Comment: Thanks James, appreciate the help